# How to prevent (and recover from) Xcode 12 NoBuildableEntriesError errors?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, xcode12

Sometimes when I reopen an existing Swift UI project in Xcode 12, the component preview pane fails to display previews of components and displays the following error message instead:

```
NoBuildableEntriesError: active scheme does not build this file

Select a scheme that builds a target which contains the current file, 
or add this file to a target that is built by the current scheme.
```

How can I resolve this and prevent it from happening again?

In particular, how can I:

1. "select a scheme that builds a target which contains the current file", and/or
2. "add this file to a target that is built by the current scheme."

Answer (score 0):

Below is the Scheme it is at the very top of Xcode you can click it to change it.
[image: Scheme]

And the membership is in the file inspector. Just click the `Target` you want.

[image: Target Membership]

My `CustomPicker.swift` files does NOT belong to StackOverflow14-Multi (macOS)

Comment: So _Target_ = _Scheme_?

Comment: A part of the Scheme has many options you can Edit Scheme and change many settings. The names match.